# Trying to make a matrix class work

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

my professor gave us a C++ implementation of a matrix class, but I am having trouble making it work.

```
template<typename T>
class matrix {
public:
    matrix(int rows = 0, int cols = 0);

    matrix<T> operator+(const matrix<T>&);
    matrix<T> operator*(const matrix<T>&);
    matrix<T> transpose(const matrix<T>&);


    int rows;
    int cols;
    T* element;


};

template <typename T>
matrix<T>::matrix(int rows, int cols) {

//if rows or cols <0, throw exception

this->rows = rows;
this->cols = cols;

element = new T [rows][cols];
}
```

In my cpp file, I am creating a matrix object like this:

```
matrix<int> m1(2,2);
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
non-constant expression as array bound

 : while compiling class template member function 'matrix<T>::matrix(int,int)'
 see reference to class template instantiation 'matrix<T>' being compiled
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int (*)[1]' to 'int *'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast,
 C-  style cast or function-style cast
```

I have no idea what's going on lol, am I not creating the object correctly? And I guess once I figure that out, is this how I would add elements to the actual array?

```
m1.element[0] = 3;
m1.element[1] = 2;
m1.element[2] = 6;
m1.element[3] = 9;
```

Comment: Somewhat related: Among the things wrong with this implementation is a failure to closely adhere to the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). You're going to find yourself tracking down crashes sooner or later until that is resolved. Regarding your error, C++ does not support variadic arrays. You need to allocate all of the elements in a *single* sequence and do the offset math yourself when addressing them. I.e. `element = new T[rows*cols];`

Comment: @WhozCraig this isn't the full implementation, it's just the parts I thought relevant since I'm just trying to create the object first. This is what I had actually written on Visual Studio but now that I'm looking more closely at the professor's implementation, it actually is T [rows*cols], I was just reading it wrong!

Comment: Eventually you'll realize it actually should be `std::vector<T> element;` and the constructor should simply have `element(rows*cols)` in the initializer list (which is incidentally where your `rows` and `cols` members also belong). That solves a number of things, including giving you RO3-compliance for free with no additional work on your part.

Answer (score 1):

This `element = new T [rows][cols];` should be `element = new T [rows*cols];` You cannot allocate 2d array in c++.

Then you can acces `i,j` element as `[i*rows+j]`.

But you should override `T & operator () (int,int)`

Don't forget destructor and `delete[]`

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
element = new T [rows][cols];
```

To:

```
element = new T [rows*cols];
```